# the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` (but the function returns a `Result`)

Tags: rust, geotiff

I have function that returns a `Result` and I am using the `?` operation on it. What is the catch?
Function:

```rust
pub fn open(filename: &str) -> Result<Box<TIFF>> {
    let tiff_reader = TIFFReader;
    tiff_reader.load(filename)
}
```

MRE:

```rust
use geotiff::TIFF;

fn main() {
    let res = TIFF::open("geotiff.tif")?;
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Compiler:

```
the `?` operator can only be used in a function that returns `Result` or `Option` (or another type that implements `std::ops::Try`)

cannot use the `?` operator in a function that returns `()`

help: the trait `std::ops::Try` is not implemented for `()`
note: required by `std::ops::Try::from_error`rustc(E0277)
```

Comment: Not *on* a function, but *in* a function. You do not show where you are calling `TIFF::open` (your question does not contain an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).

Comment: @justinas is added the code that I am using.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got the docs wrong. It's supposed to be used inside a function. Please post this as an answer.

Comment: Does the following help @virtumonde https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/error-handling-and-panics/question-mark-in-main-and-tests.html

Comment: Thank you @Jason this is perfect. I got it the other way initially.

Comment: @justinas Yes, I agree this is a duplicate.